# System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction (randomly occurs)

Tags: c#, soap

I'm currently stuck on an error that I am getting from one of our web services. The error is:

System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction:
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)

What I have logged about this error:
It seems to occur randomly
It started around the same time our services were migrated.
Prior to the migration there were no errors.

Any trouble shooting tips would be appreciated. Also please note I have gone through the similar questions on stack overflow along with Googling this error, I have not been able to fix this with answers provided, I'm hoping someone can bring some new insight.

Comment: Do you get that error from a valid client? Or is someone accessing service URL's with a browser? Have you turned on [message logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx)? Were your **servers** migrated, or did the services get migrated to another server? Is it possible they're now behind some different proxy or load balancer?

Comment: Maybe this is a hint you should stop using ASMX web services, which are a legacy technology? No?

Comment: @CodeCaster: he's using ASMX, or he could trivially turn on message logging and be done by now.

Comment: Hello, the servers were migrated. As for message logging not sure if its an option. I don't have access to the server, only an ftp where I can drop the service to.  They are behind a load balancer.